# mod_rewrite is ignoring rules in subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

**Wanted rewrite behaviour** (internal rewrite!)

```
http://<subdomain>.domain.tld/<path> -> /<subdomain>/<path>
http://www.domain.tld/path/file.php  -> /www/path/file.php
http://project.domain-tld/index.php  -> /project/index.php
```

**Folder structure:**

```
/                        root
    .htaccess
    /www                 www.domain.tld
        index.php
        /www
            file.php
        /foo
            /bar
                file.php
    /project             project.domain.tld
        index.php
        someRandomFiles
    /somesubdomain       somesubdomain.domain.tld
        index.php
        someRandomFiles
    /anothersubdomain    anothersubdomain.domain.tld
         index.php
         someRandomFiles
```

**Full .htaccess**

```
# Unicode
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Activate mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Subdomains
#  Extract (required) subdomain (%1), and first path element (%3), discard port number if present (%2)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<>%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.janbuschtoens\.de(:80)?<>/([^/]*) [NC]
#  Rewrite only when subdomain not equal to first path element (prevents mod_rewrite recursion)
RewriteCond %1<>%3 !^(.*)<>\1$ [NC]
#  Rewrite to /subdomain/path
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

My `.htaccess` seems to work. You can live test it here:

- http://test.janbuschtoens.de/
  rewrites to `/test/`
- http://www.janbuschtoens.de/ 
  rewrites to `/www/`

But there is some strange behaviour in subdirectories. `mod_rewrite` seems to ignore the rule if the first directory in the requested path has the same name as the subdomain itself. For example:

- `http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/file.php  -> /www/foo/bar/file.php - Fine!`
- `http://www.domain.tld/                  -> /www/     - Fine!`
- `http://www.domain.tld/www/              -> /www/     - Should be: /www/www/`
- `http://www.domain.tld/www/www/          -> /www/www/ - Should be: /www/www/www/`

For another live test:

- http://test.janbuschtoens.de/ rewrites to `/test/`
- http://test.janbuschtoens.de/test/ rewrites to `/test/`

It seems like the rule gets ignored.

Comment: 1) Can you please tell what are you trying to achieve? Please show few examples (from url => to url). 2) Where this .htaccess is located -- I guess in root folder and you have no such files in subdomain folders?

Comment: OK, I have enough info. I just need to find some time to do it. Hopefully I will have some spare time shortly, otherwise I will have to comeback to this after work (in 6 hours or so). I hope you can wait :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only good rule that I was able come up with, otherwise after initial rewriting (which is very easy) it goes into the loop (and that is the problem). For example: `www.domain.com/www/123.png` gets properly redirected into `/www/www/123.png`, but then goes to the next loop, where it get's redirected to `/www/www/www/123.png` and then again and again.

This rule **ONLY** gets invoked if FINAL filename **DOES EXIST**.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

For example: if you request `www.domain.com/www/123.png`, and file/folder `WEBSITEROOT/www/www/123.png` exist, then it will be rewritten, otherwise nothing.

The same here: if you request `meow.domain.com/` .. but have no `WEBSITEROOT/meow/` folder on your drive, it gets nowhere.

Please note, this still will not help much if you have subfolder with the same name as subdomain. For example: if you request `www.domain.com` it should be rewritten to `WEBSITEROOT/www/` ... but if you also have `WEBSITEROOT/www/www/` then (because of loop) it will be rewritten to `WEBSITEROOT/www/www/` instead.

Unfortunately I have not found the way how to bypass it. If you wish -- you can try combining your rules with mine.

Comment: Thanks for your solution - Would it help, if I move my subdomains to a subfolder called "subdomains"? So that all my subdomains are not located in /, but in /subdomains/.

Comment: @silvinci It should help with resolving the last point (last 2 paragraphs of my answer). But you should try .. it really hard to guarantee this without trying myself.